# Django 1.8 dynamic url configuration based on variable

Tags: python, django

This seems to not work in django:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^%s/admin/' %(BASE_PATH), include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^%s/$' %(BASE_PATH), home_view),
    url(r'^%s/ping/$' %(BASE_PATH), ping),
    url(r'^%s/echo/$' %(BASE_PATH), echo),
    url(gcd_str, gcd),
]
```

If I set the BASE_PATH to 'test' and go to http://host/test/echo I get a 404 error but my paths look like this on the error page:

```
^/test/admin/
^/test/$
^/test/ping/$
^/test/echo/$
^/test/gcd/$
```

If I hard-code like this it works:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^test/$', home_view),
    url(r'^test/ping/$', ping),
    url(r'^test/echo/$', echo),
]
```

I guess that the pattern does not get interpolated correctly, if I use a string without the `r` it seems to behave the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting `BASE_PATH` to

```
/test
```

Where as when you hardcode then you write it as

```
test
```

The starting `/` makes all the difference, as the url pattern expects ( as per `BASE_PATH` is the one that starts with

```
^/test/admin/
|| |
|| matches test
|matches /
matches start of the pattern
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I didn't notice that.